# Unable to run yum update on centos 7

Tags: yum

Not able to run yum update. It fails with the message connection refused.

When I run sudo yum update I get the following message

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=genclo error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed connect to localhost:3000; Connection refused"
```

---

I am able to connect to internet.

Comment: Please don't post your error message in heading format, this is very misleading. You could use the code formatting instead. Anyway, as it sais, it tries connecting to `localhost:3000` instead of contacting `mirrorlist.centos.org` directly. Possibly there is kind of a local proxy server configured, but not running. You should find out where this `localhost:3000` is coming from and deactivate it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

1. Find your appropriate version on next site (in this example I'm using **7.0.1406**):

   https://vault.centos.org/
2. Execute next commands to update your yum configuration files:

   > sed -i -e 's/mirrorlist=/#mirrorlist=/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

   > sed -i -e 's/mirrorlist=/#mirrorlist=/g' /etc/yum.conf

   > sed -E -i -e 's/#baseurl=http:\/\/mirror.centos.org\/centos\/\$releasever\/([[:alnum:]_-]*)\/\$basearch\//baseurl=https:\/\/vault.centos.org\/7.0.1406\/\1\/\$basearch\//g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

   > sed -E -i -e 's/#baseurl=http:\/\/mirror.centos.org\/centos\/\$releasever\/([[:alnum:]_-]*)\/\$basearch\//baseurl=https:\/\/vault.centos.org\/7.0.1406\/\1\/\$basearch\//g' /etc/yum.conf

Good Luck!